# Nokia Lumia 925 does not fully charge

Tags: battery

My Nokia Lumia 925 does not charge fully. The phone's battery has already been replaced one month ago. T-Mobile said because I did not use a Nokia charger plug.

Is there a fix?

Comment: Did you try to fully drain the battery before charging it? do this recycle of totally drain then charge for like 3 times and the battery should be ok after that.

Comment: What model?  it may not be easy - but all batteries can be removed/replaced.

Comment: How old is the battery? How long does it last?

Comment: It's a 925 and a month old.

Comment: battery charge goes before 12 hrs;

Comment: "Does not charge fully?" does that means the charge indicator gets to a certain percentage and then just stops charging, or that the phone battery only last 12 hours? If the later, is the phone idle most of the time, or are you playing games, watching videos, etc?

Comment: Have you tried using the Nokia charger plug?

Answer (score 2):

Third party chargers are known to be of significantly lower quality than name-brand chargers. I used a Samsung charger with my HTC 8x that ruined the battery within a month and bricked the phone.

[This Blog](http://www.righto.com/2012/10/a-dozen-usb-chargers-in-lab-apple-is.html) shows exactly why you want to use a name-brand charger and the kind of damage that cheap off-brand chargers can do to your phone. It gets very technical, but is well written and explains everything on a level understandable by the layman.

As far as recovering your current battery, it's not likely. You can try a full drain/charge cycle as HaLaBi said, but fully draining lithium ion or NiMH batteries can do damage of its own (rather, it reduces the overall lifetime of the battery). I recommend that you get a new, Nokia branded charger and then replace the battery with a new one (again).

If you're an engineer (which would mean you probably wouldn't be asking this question) you can try a high voltage shock to the battery to rejuvinate it. This is dangerous and can explode your battery, but there are youtube videos of it working with NiMH batteries and there are car-chargers designed to do this with lead-acid car batteries. If you do try this, note that it will void any warranty you had and please please PLEASE use proper safety procedures!

:EDIT:
I should append that I went through 2 phones before I realized it was the charger. On the 2nd warranty replacement, I experienced shorter battery life like you describe. I started using the HTC charger that came with the phone (before the phone became bricked like the first) and my battery life returned to near normal after the first full charge/discharge/charge cycle. It never did hold a charge like the new phone, though. Permanent damage was done to the battery.